# Node.js - Defined a function yet throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a chat app. I was using express-validator.

```
const express = require('express');
const validator = require('express-validator');

const container = require('./container');


function ConfigureExpress(app){
        app.use(express.static('public'));
        app.use(cookieParser());
        app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

        app.use(validator());

        app.use(session({
            secret: 'thisisasecretkey',
            resave: true,
            saveInitialized: true,
            store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection})
        }));

        app.use(flash());

        app.use(passport.initialize());
        app.use(passport.session());
    }
```

This is the error getting thrown when I run nodemon server:

```
C:\Users\Utkarsh Rai\aqchat\server.js:49
        app.use(validator());
                ^

TypeError: validator is not a function
```

I tried to resolve the issue, but am not able to understand where am I going wrong. I tried searching for this issue.

Comment: As best I can tell by looking at [the doc](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/check-api.html), `app.use(validator());` is not how you use express-validator.

Comment: I've just started out and I don't exactly have the idea for the correct usage.

Comment: Well, start by reading the documentation and following some of the examples there. We don't just teach you how to use something from scratch here that has documentation. You study, you learn, you try some things that are consistent with the documentation. Then, if you get stuck on a specific problem, you post here with what you tried, what problem you ran into and where you got stuck. There's no such thing as a generic validator middleware (like you're trying to use).  You have to specify what fields on what specific request to validate and what the validation constraints are for that request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you used express-validator is not correct.
you have to import validationResult from express-validator.

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator')
```

the define your own middle ware

```
const validate = (req, res, next) => {
const errors = validationResult(req)
if (errors.isEmpty()) {
    return next()
 }

//do whatever you want with errors

return res.status(500).json({
   errors: errors,
})
}
```

and use this middleware in your app.js

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/index.html):

```
// ...rest of the initial code omitted for simplicity.
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

app.post('/user', [
  // username must be an email
  check('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], (req, res) => {
  // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }).then(user => res.json(user));
});
```

So instead you'll want to create your own validation method like:

```
function ConfigureExpress(app){
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    //Our validator code
    app.use([
        /*
        ex. validator.check('username').isAlphanumeric()
        */
    ]);

    app.use(session({
        secret: 'thisisasecretkey',
        resave: true,
        saveInitialized: true,
        store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection})
    }));

    app.use(flash());

    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
}
```

Comment: Maybe, but it looks like a simple overlook. Giving the benefit of the doubt, he'll see that not all express middleware is a function with an options parameter.

Answer (score -1):

express-validator change the rule at the latest version

please take a look [Click Here](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/)

Comment: Answers with no content other than a link pointing to the documentation are not appropriate here.  If you know a solution to the question, then write your own text that explains the answer.